# inotify event IN_MODIFY occurring twice for tftp put

Tags: c, linux, file, inotify, tftp

I am using inotify to listen to modifications to a file.

When I test file modification, program is working fine.

```
# echo "test" > /tftpboot/.TEST

Output:
Read 16 data
IN_MODIFY
```

But when I do tftp put, two events are generated:

```
tftp>  put .TEST
Sent 6 bytes in 0.1 seconds
tftp>

Output:
Read 16 data
IN_MODIFY
Read 16 data
IN_MODIFY
```

Any idea how to avoid the duplicate notification?

Code is given below:

```
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int fd = inotify_init();
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        cout << "inotify_init failed\n";
        return 1;
    }
    int wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, "/tftpboot/.TEST", IN_MODIFY);
    if (wd < 0)
    {
        cout << "inotify_add_watch failed\n";
        return 1;
    }
    while (true)
    {
        char buffer[sizeof(struct inotify_event) + NAME_MAX + 1] = {0};
        ssize_t length;

        do
        {
            length = read( fd, buffer, sizeof(struct inotify_event));
            cout << "Read " << length << " data\n";
        }while (length < 0);

        if (length < 0)
        {
            cout << "read failed\n";
            return 1;
        }

        struct inotify_event *event = ( struct inotify_event * ) buffer;
        if ( event->mask & IN_ACCESS )
            cout << "IN_ACCESS\n";
        if ( event->mask & IN_CLOSE_WRITE )
            cout << "IN_CLOSE_WRITE\n";
        if ( event->mask & IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE )
            cout << "IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE\n";
        if ( event->mask & IN_MODIFY )
            cout << "IN_MODIFY \n";
        if ( event->mask & IN_OPEN )
            cout << "IN_OPEN\n";
    }

    inotify_rm_watch( fd, wd );
    close (fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try using `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` instead

> **Q**: What is the difference between **IN_MODIFY** and **IN_CLOSE_WRITE**?
>
> The
>   IN_MODIFY event is emitted on a file content change (e.g. via the
>   write() syscall) while IN_CLOSE_WRITE occurs on closing the changed
>   file. It means each change operation causes one IN_MODIFY event (it
>   may occur many times during manipulations with an open file) whereas
>   IN_CLOSE_WRITE is emitted only once (on closing the file).
>
> **Q**: Is it better to use **IN_MODIFY** or **IN_CLOSE_WRITE**?
>
> It varies from
>   case to case. Usually it is more suitable to use IN_CLOSE_WRITE
>   because if emitted the all changes on the appropriate file are safely
>   written inside the file. The IN_MODIFY event needn't mean that a file
>   change is finished (data may remain in memory buffers in the
>   application). On the other hand, many logs and similar files must be
>   monitored using IN_MODIFY - in such cases where these files are
>   permanently open and thus no IN_CLOSE_WRITE can be emitted.

[source](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=inotify&page=faq&lang=en)