# Suppress or prevent duplicate inotifywait events?

Tags: linux, git, inotify, inotifywait

Currently `inotifywait` is watching git server folders. End it emits only when specific file modified. The problem is, when changes are pushed to git server, `inotifywait` triggers few times. I don’t know why.

So how can I do the next: prevent `inotifywait` from making duplicates?

I was thinking about the algorithm: when triggered first time->sleep script so it won’t scan next changes for 5 seconds->resume script. But it sounds idiotic... Can you help me achieving this? Thanks!!

Comment: You should probably show the relevant part of your code. Maybe related: [inotify event IN_MODIFY occurring twice for tftp put](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32377517/608639). According to the accepted answer, you should probably use `IN_CLOSE_WRITE`. Also see [Why do inotify events fire more than once](https://askubuntu.com/q/710422) on Ubuntu.SE.

Comment: Which exactly file do you track? It could be that it changed not once.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45270254/6309), you can setup first a post-receive hook which would checkout the repo for you whenever there is a push done to the Git server.

Not only can you test your `inotify` function when monitoring those files changed on checkout, but you could even consider *not* using `inotify` at all, and using the hook to trigger your notification.
A [`post-receive` hook can list files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9478883/6309), and you can then trigger your notification only for certain files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it for my own needs. I am monitoring a path so that it will auto-compile for syntax errors. And I was bothered with the duplicate events emitted by `inotifywait`. Add the `syncheck` function into your `.bashrc`:

```
syncheck() {
  declare -A fileMap
  inotifywait --exclude .swp --format '%w%f' -e modify,create -m -r -q $* | \
  while read FILE; do
    es=$(date +'%s')
    case "$FILE" in
    *.hs)
    if [[ ${fileMap[$FILE]} != $es ]];then
        sdiff=$((es-${fileMap[$FILE]:-0}))
        fileMap[$FILE]=$es
        ((sdiff < 3)) && continue
        ghc -fno-code $FILE
        echo "---------------------------------------------"
    fi
    ;;
    esac
  done
}
```

How to use:

```
cd ~/src/proj/
. ~/.bashrc
syncheck .
```

In another terminal, modify or create a `Haskell` file in `~/src/proj/` location. The `syncheck` while-loop will detect this and auto-compile for syntax errors.

The key idea to this duplicate events suppression solution is Unix`s epoch seconds and bash dictionary.